# Tiny mce template content non-editable

Tags: templates, tinymce, readonly

I'm using newest tinymce editor and have one specific problem.

I would like to make all template elements (tags) non editable, so user can edit only text inside them.

Can anyone please help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: this is a very complex task to do!

Answer (score 0):

i have already achieve this but i think my work around is not a good one.. but at least the problem is solved. anyway here is my solution.

tinymce currently has a bug in noneditables, because when you press and hold the delete button  starting from an editable content it would also delete the noneditable content.

so what i did:

the form this will be the input field

```
<div class="nonEditables" style="width:100%;"></div>
<div> "Placeholder" </div>
<div class="nonEditables" style="width:100%;"></div>
```

bind keyup event on tinymce on initiate

```
ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed, e) {
    if ($('.nonEditables').length < 2) {
        tinymce.UndoManager.undo();
    }
// DO ANYTHING HERE.. the checking and everything you need. 
});
```

this works for me... and also do a checking if the Placeholder is deleted or else tinymce will remove the div... and you will loose your input field... :) always put a text inside.. (*a space will do, " ") :)